Websockets via python-telegram-bot
I'm trying to create a chat between users using websockets, asyncio and python-telegram-bot 21.1.1.
Here is my code:
Function where I'm listening websockets in ws.py:
async def run_ws(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        async with websockets.connect(f"{main.URL}/{main.CHAT_ID}/", user_agent_header="tg_user") as websocket:
            while True:
                response = await websocket.recv()
                try:
                    message_data = json.loads(response)
                    message_content = message_data.get("message")
                    message_sender = message_data.get("username")
                    if message_content == "disconnected":
                        await context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, main.DISCONNECTED_MESSAGE)
                        main.IS_CONNECTED = False
                        break
                    elif message_sender == f'tg_{update.effective_user.id}':
                        continue
                    else:
                        await context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, f"{message_content}")
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    await context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, response)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

And below I'm trying send message to websockets:
async def send_to_ws(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    print(main.IS_CONNECTED)
    if main.IS_CONNECTED is True:
        try:
            async with websockets.connect(f"{main.URL}/{main.CHAT_ID}/", user_agent_header="tg_user") as websocket:
                print(update.message.text)
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({"message": f"{update.message.text}", "user": f"tg_{update.effective_user.id}"}))
                await websocket.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

Also I added handlers in main.py:
application.add_handler(CommandHandler('run_ws', ws.run_ws))
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, ws.send_to_ws))

Now the problem is that I can read messages coming to me from WS, but I cannot send messages via Telegram while the connection is active(run_ws). And I don't understand how I can run these two pieces of code at the same time or maybe there is a better solution altogether?
